# how to assign custom key value to array?

Tags: javascript

How can I turn this [ [{name:"TSLA", price: 234}], [{name:"SHOP", price: 22}] ] into this [ {stock:[{name:"TSLA", price: 234}]}, {stock: [{name:"SHOP", price: 22}]} ]. I have tried following but this gets me [ { '0': [ [Object] ] }, { '1': [] } ]. So instead of '0' and '1', I need them to be stock.

```
const a = [ [{name:"TSLA", price: 234}], [{name:"SHOP", price: 22}] ]

let b = Object.keys(a).map((stock) => {
  let output ={};
  output[stock] = a[stock]
  return output
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `stock` variable is actually an index of an array within an array. If you want to use the string `'stock'` as a property name of your array in the output object, you need to assign an array at the given index to the string `'stock'`. You can do it the following way:

```js
const array = [
  [{name:'TSLA', price: 234}],
  [{name:'SHOP', price: 22}]
];

const output = Object
  .keys(array)
  .map(index => ({
    'stock': array[index]
  }));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for.